# What are good services for checking the external IP of a machine?

Tags: api, networking, ip

I'm working with an API that requires the machine's external IP. [I have come understand](https://serverfault.com/questions/222113/can-i-determine-a-machines-outward-facing-ip-with-php-without-relying-on-externa/222123#222123) that I can't do this without relying on an external server.

I've used whatismyip.com in the past:

`wget -q -O - http://whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp`

What are some other services for checking the external IP of a machine? Since I'm concerned about a single point of failure, I'd like to have a few options to which I can fail over.

Comment: Here's the shortest one I've found: http://onlyip.org

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org | sed 's/[a-zA-Z/<> :]//g'
```

Now, I didn't write that myself, just doing some research for you.

http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/04/checking-your-internal-and-external-ip-addresses-on-a-unix-machine/

Or

```
wget -O -q icanhazip.com
```

Comment: Consider mentioning that icanhazip has ipv4. and ipv6. subdomains.

Comment: Errata: `wget -O - -q icanhazip.com`

Answer (score 5):

http://api.externalip.net/ip works fine for me, great uptime and fast. no reg exp needed

Comment: suspended from marth...

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.showmemyip.com
- http://www.whatismy.com
- http://showip.codebrainz.ca/ ([details](http://codebrainz.ca/index.php/2009/09/11/web-service-to-get-external-ip-address/))

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I need an API-like service. Based on whatismyip.com, apparently some of these sites will try to block what appear to be bots.

Comment: @editor: so you're looking for a web service?

Comment: @ditor: how about http://showip.codebrainz.ca/

Comment: Thanks for the question! Yes, looking for an API or something that won't mind me hitting it as if it was an API

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for, thank you